# Switching between screens from python code not KV

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I'm new to Kivy
I want to manage the changes between the screens in Python and not in KV
I wrote a function in Python when the button is pressed in the popup window the screen will change to the second screen
As you can see in the terminal the values ​​are seemingly correct [unlike previous versions I got an error there is no such name second screen ]
What I do not do correct? why the function does not switch to a second screen?

PY

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen  
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty ,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MainWindow(Screen):

def set(self):

   x=9

   y=8

   print(x,y)

   show_popupw()

def change_screen(self):
    print("c_S")
    self.sm = ScreenManager()
    self.sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))
    self.sm.current = 'second'
    print(self.sm)
    print(self.sm.current)
  



def show_popupw():

show = Pow()



popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))



popupWindow.open()

    



class SecondWindow(Screen):

a = NumericProperty()

def sec(self):

    self.a = self.a + 1

    print(self.a)

   






class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
   pass





 kv = Builder.load_file('mymainsctaq.kv')





class Pow(FloatLayout):

  

    mainw=MainWindow()     


class mymainscreenApp(App):

    def build(self):
     

      return kv





if __name__ == "__main__":

   mymainscreenApp().run()
```

KV

```
  WindowManager:

  MainWindow:

  SecondWindow:

 <MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:

    cols:2
    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        Label:

            text: "name: "



        TextInput:

            id: name

            multiline: False



    Button:

        text: "Submit"

        on_release:
            app.root.current = "second" if name.text == "go" else "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    Button:

        text: "set"

        on_release:

            root.set()





<SecondWindow>:
   name: 'second'
   GridLayout:

    cols:2



    GridLayout:

        cols: 4

       

          

        Label:

            text: "num: "  + str(root.a)

        Button:

            text: "Go Back"

            on_press:

                

                app.root.current = "main"

                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"

                root.sec()



<Pow>:

   Label:

    text: "You set?"

    size_hint: 0.6, 0.2

    pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}



Button:

    text: "ok,set"

    size_hint: 0.8, 0.2

    pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}                   

    on_release:
        root.mainw.change_screen()
```

Answer (score 0):

In calling a function from the same class in python, you need to specify that you are calling the function from the same class using `self`.

So in your .py file in your code. When you call the function `show_popupw()` in the `MainWindow` class you need to use `self`.

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    def set(self):
       x=9
       y=8

       print(x,y)
       self.show_popupw()
```

And also, you need to set your `show_popupw` function with a `self` `parameter` as well. Because you will be passing its `self` for `reference`.

```
def show_popupw(self):
    show = Pow()
    popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window",
                        content=show,
                        size_hint=(None,None),
                        size=(400,400))
    popupWindow.open()
```

Your .py file should look like this then:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen  
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty ,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def set(self):
       x=9
       y=8

       print(x,y)
       self.show_popupw()

    def change_screen(self):
        print("c_S")
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))
        self.sm.current = 'second'
        print(self.sm)
        print(self.sm.current)

    def show_popupw(self):
        show = Pow()
        popupWindow = Popup(title="Popup Window",
                            content=show,
                            size_hint=(None,None),
                            size=(400,400))
        popupWindow.open()

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    a = NumericProperty()

    def sec(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1
        print(self.a)

class WindowChanger(ScreenManager):
   pass

class Pow(FloatLayout):
    mainw=MainWindow()  

kv = Builder.load_file('mymainsctaq.kv')

class mymainscreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
   mymainscreenApp().run()
```